# trying to dynamically remove / add hide class to manipulate DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

I am working on a project, which is to clone a cinema website as close as possible. I have a group of buttons, each of which are associated with list elements. When a user clicks one of the buttons I want to remove a **css** class I have set which is `display: none` from the list elements in relation to the button clicked, and at the same time apply the same **CSS** class to the list elements which are not related to it.

**The problem:**

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. What isn't helping is the fact that the console is not displaying any sort of error message. What is happening is ALL the list elements are having the **css** class applied, but the list elements which i want to have displayed are not showing.

Please have a look below at my code

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="container">

        <section class="showtimes">

            <ul class="screening-days">

        <li class="selectday active" id="clickMon">Monday</li>
        <li class="selectday" id="clickTue">Tuesday</li>
        <li class="selectday" id="clickWed">Wednesday</li>
        <li class="selectday" id="clickThur">Thursday</li>
        <li class="selectday" id="clickFri">Friday</li>
        <li class="selectday" id="clickSat">Saturday</li>
        <li class="selectday" id="clickSun">Sunday</li>
        <li>Coming Soon</li>

            </ul>

            <span class="filter">

                <p>Filter Films</p>

            </span>

        </section>

    </div>

    <div class="movie-showtimes">

            <ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">

                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>10:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>13:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>15:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>18:25</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>20:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>21:50</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>13:50</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>15:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>17:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>20:00</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>22:50</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>10:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>13:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>15:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>18:25</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>20:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>21:50</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="classic-movie">

        <div class="movie-summary">

            <div class="movie-image">

                <img src="images/movie-images/back-to-the-future.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">

            </div>

            <div class="movie-name-plot">

                <h1>Back to the Future (1985)</h1>

                <p>Marty McFly, a typical American teenager of the Eighties, is accidentally sent back to 1955 in a plutonium-powered DeLorean 'time machine' invented by a slightly mad scientist. During his often hysterical, always amazing trip back in time, Marty must make certain his teenage parents-to-be meet and fall in love - so he can get back to the future.</p> 

                <p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span> Michael J. Fox, Christopher Lloyd, Lea Thompson</p>

                <p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>116 min</p>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="movie-showtimes">

            <ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">

                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>11:20</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>14:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>16:50</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>18:00</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>19:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>22:15</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>14:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>16:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>18:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>20:35</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>21:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>22:45</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>10:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>13:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>15:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>18:25</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>20:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>21:50</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>

            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="classic-movie">

        <div class="movie-summary">

            <div class="movie-image">

                <img src="images/movie-images/first-blood.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">

            </div>

            <div class="movie-name-plot">

                <h1>First Blood (1982)</h1>

                <p>John Rambo is a disoriented Vietnam Vet. He is hitchhiking from town to town to see friends from the war. A sheriff tries to make him leave town and when he refuses, arrests him for vagrancy. While in jail, a deputy takes delight in abusing him. Rambo escapes showing his old Vietnam fighting skills and takes to the woods as the sheriff and deputies try and find him in his element. Things get out of hand as Colonel Trautman, Rambo's old commander, appears to shed light on the situation.</p> 

                <p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span>Sylvester Stallone, Brian Dennehy, Richard Crenna</p>

                <p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>93 min</p>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="movie-showtimes">

            <ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">

                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>10:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>13:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>17:00</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>18:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>20:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>22:00</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>13:50</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>15:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>17:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>20:00</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>22:50</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>14:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>16:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>18:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>20:35</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>21:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>22:45</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>

            </ul>


        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="classic-movie">

        <div class="movie-summary">

            <div class="movie-image">

                <img src="images/movie-images/breakfast-club.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">

            </div>

            <div class="movie-name-plot">

                <h1>The Breakfast Club (1985)</h1>

                <p>They were five students with nothing in common, faced with spending a Saturday detention together in their high school library. At 7 a.m., they had nothing to say, but by 4 p.m., they had bared their souls to each other and become good friends. To the outside world they were simply a Brain, an Athlete, a Basket Case, a Princess, and a Criminal, but to each other, they would always be the Breakfast Club.</p> 

                <p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span>Emilio Estevez, Judd Nelson, Molly Ringwald</p>

                <p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>97 min</p>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="movie-showtimes">

            <ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">

                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>13:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>14:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>18:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>19:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>20:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>22:30</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>13:50</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>15:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>17:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>20:00</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>22:50</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>10:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>13:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>15:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>18:25</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>20:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>21:50</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>

            </ul>


        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="classic-movie">

        <div class="movie-summary">

            <div class="movie-image">

                <img src="images/movie-images/halloween.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">

            </div>

            <div class="movie-name-plot">

                <h1>Halloween (1979)</h1>

                <p>The year is 1963, the night: Halloween. Police are called to 43 Lampkin Ln. only to discover that 15 year old Judith Myers has been stabbed to death, by her 6 year-old brother, Michael. After being institutionalized for 15 years, Myers breaks out on the night before Halloween. No one knows, nor wants to find out, what will happen on October 31st 1978 besides Myers' psychiatrist, Dr. Loomis. He knows Michael is coming back to Haddonfield, but by the time the town realizes it, it'll be too late for many people.</p> 

                <p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span>Donald Pleasence, Jamie Lee Curtis, Tony Moran</p>

                <p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>91 min</p>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="movie-showtimes">

            <ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">

                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>14:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>16:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>18:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>20:35</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>21:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>22:45</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>13:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>15:00</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>18:00</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>18:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>22:15</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>16:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>17:00</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>19:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>20:00</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>21:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>22:30</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>12:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>13:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>15:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>16:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>19:00</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>22:30</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>16:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>17:00</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>19:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>20:00</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>21:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>22:30</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>14:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>16:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>20:35</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>21:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>22:45</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>12:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>13:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>15:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>16:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>19:00</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>22:30</li>

            </ul>


        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="classic-movie">

        <div class="movie-summary">

            <div class="movie-image">

                <img src="images/movie-images/goodfellas.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">

            </div>

            <div class="movie-name-plot">

                <h1>Goodfellas (1990)</h1>

                <p>Henry Hill might be a small time gangster, who may have taken part in a robbery with Jimmy Conway and Tommy De Vito, two other gangsters who might have set their sights a bit higher. His two partners could kill off everyone else involved in the robbery, and slowly start to think about climbing up through the hierarchy of the Mob. Henry, however, might be badly affected by his partners' success, but will he consider stooping low enough to bring about the downfall of Jimmy and Tommy?</p> 

                <p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span>Robert De Niro, Ray Liotta, Joe Pesci</p>

                <p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>146 min</p>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="movie-showtimes">

            <ul class="movie-timing mon-listings show">

                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>12:25</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>13:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>14:50</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>17:35</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>20:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>22:30</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>13:50</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>15:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>17:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>20:00</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>22:50</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>10:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>13:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>15:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>18:25</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>20:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>21:50</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>

                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
                <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>

            </ul>


        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var daytimeshow = document.querySelectorAll(".selectday");
    var showtimeListings = document.querySelectorAll(".daytimeshow");
    var mondayShowings = document.querySelectorAll(".mondaylisting");
    var tuesdayShowings = document.querySelectorAll(".tuesdaylisting");
    var wednesdayShowings = document.querySelectorAll(".wednesdaylisting");
    var thursdayShowings = document.querySelectorAll(".thursdaylisting");
    var fridayShowings = document.querySelectorAll(".fridaylisting");
    var saturdayShowings = document.querySelectorAll(".saturdaylisting");

        for (var i = 0; i < daytimeshow.length; i++){
        daytimeshow[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            if (this.id === "clickTue"){
                for (var i = 0; i < showtimeListings.length; i++){
                    if (showtimeListings[i].classList === "tuesdaylisting"){
                        showtimeListings[i].classList.remove("hideElement");
                    } else {
                        showtimeListings[i].classList.add("hideElement");
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }



});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have multiple class names on each element, you should use `contains()` instead of `===` for comparing class names:

```
if (showtimeListings[i].classList.contains("tuesdaylisting"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have corrected your logic. Take a look at the below snippet. Cleaned up the logic which shows the tuesdaylisting. Removed this.id and redeclaration of i var in nested for loop. Used contains, add, remove from classList.

Click on tuesday to see it in action.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var daytimeshow = document.querySelectorAll(".selectday");
  var showtimeListings = document.querySelectorAll(".daytimeshow");
  var mondayShowings = document.querySelectorAll(".mondaylisting");
  var tuesdayShowings = document.querySelectorAll(".tuesdaylisting");
  var wednesdayShowings = document.querySelectorAll(".wednesdaylisting");
  var thursdayShowings = document.querySelectorAll(".thursdaylisting");
  var fridayShowings = document.querySelectorAll(".fridaylisting");
  var saturdayShowings = document.querySelectorAll(".saturdaylisting");
  for (var i = 0; i < daytimeshow.length; i++) {
    daytimeshow[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      if (e.target.id === "clickTue") {
        for (var j = 0; j < showtimeListings.length; j++) {
          var classList = showtimeListings[j].classList;
          classList.contains("tuesdaylisting") ? classList.remove("hideElement") : classList.add("hideElement");
        }
      }
    })
  }



});
```

```css
.hideElement {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <section class="showtimes">

    <ul class="screening-days">

      <li class="selectday active" id="clickMon">Monday</li>
      <li class="selectday" id="clickTue">Tuesday</li>
      <li class="selectday" id="clickWed">Wednesday</li>
      <li class="selectday" id="clickThur">Thursday</li>
      <li class="selectday" id="clickFri">Friday</li>
      <li class="selectday" id="clickSat">Saturday</li>
      <li class="selectday" id="clickSun">Sunday</li>
      <li>Coming Soon</li>

    </ul>

    <span class="filter">

                <p>Filter Films</p>

            </span>

  </section>

</div>

<div class="movie-showtimes">

  <ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">

    <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>10:45</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>13:10</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>15:45</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>18:25</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>20:30</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>21:50</li>

    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>13:50</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>15:10</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>17:30</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>20:00</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>22:50</li>

    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>10:45</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>13:10</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>15:45</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>18:25</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>20:30</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>21:50</li>

    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>

    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>

    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>

    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
    <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>

</div>

</div>

<div class="classic-movie">

  <div class="movie-summary">

    <div class="movie-image">

      <img src="images/movie-images/back-to-the-future.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">

    </div>

    <div class="movie-name-plot">

      <h1>Back to the Future (1985)</h1>

      <p>Marty McFly, a typical American teenager of the Eighties, is accidentally sent back to 1955 in a plutonium-powered DeLorean 'time machine' invented by a slightly mad scientist. During his often hysterical, always amazing trip back in time, Marty
        must make certain his teenage parents-to-be meet and fall in love - so he can get back to the future.</p>

      <p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span> Michael J. Fox, Christopher Lloyd, Lea Thompson</p>

      <p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>116 min</p>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="movie-showtimes">

    <ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">

      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>11:20</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>14:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>16:50</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>18:00</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>19:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>22:15</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>14:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>16:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>18:10</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>20:35</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>21:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>22:45</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>10:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>13:10</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>15:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>18:25</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>20:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>21:50</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>

    </ul>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="classic-movie">

  <div class="movie-summary">

    <div class="movie-image">

      <img src="images/movie-images/first-blood.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">

    </div>

    <div class="movie-name-plot">

      <h1>First Blood (1982)</h1>

      <p>John Rambo is a disoriented Vietnam Vet. He is hitchhiking from town to town to see friends from the war. A sheriff tries to make him leave town and when he refuses, arrests him for vagrancy. While in jail, a deputy takes delight in abusing him.
        Rambo escapes showing his old Vietnam fighting skills and takes to the woods as the sheriff and deputies try and find him in his element. Things get out of hand as Colonel Trautman, Rambo's old commander, appears to shed light on the situation.</p>

      <p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span>Sylvester Stallone, Brian Dennehy, Richard Crenna</p>

      <p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>93 min</p>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="movie-showtimes">

    <ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">

      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>10:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>13:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>17:00</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>18:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>20:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>22:00</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>13:50</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>15:10</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>17:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>20:00</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>22:50</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>14:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>16:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>18:10</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>20:35</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>21:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>22:45</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>

    </ul>


  </div>

</div>

<div class="classic-movie">

  <div class="movie-summary">

    <div class="movie-image">

      <img src="images/movie-images/breakfast-club.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">

    </div>

    <div class="movie-name-plot">

      <h1>The Breakfast Club (1985)</h1>

      <p>They were five students with nothing in common, faced with spending a Saturday detention together in their high school library. At 7 a.m., they had nothing to say, but by 4 p.m., they had bared their souls to each other and become good friends.
        To the outside world they were simply a Brain, an Athlete, a Basket Case, a Princess, and a Criminal, but to each other, they would always be the Breakfast Club.</p>

      <p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span>Emilio Estevez, Judd Nelson, Molly Ringwald</p>

      <p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>97 min</p>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="movie-showtimes">

    <ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">

      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>13:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>14:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>18:10</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>19:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>20:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>22:30</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>13:50</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>15:10</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>17:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>20:00</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>22:50</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>10:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>13:10</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>15:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>18:25</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>20:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>21:50</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>

    </ul>


  </div>

</div>

<div class="classic-movie">

  <div class="movie-summary">

    <div class="movie-image">

      <img src="images/movie-images/halloween.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">

    </div>

    <div class="movie-name-plot">

      <h1>Halloween (1979)</h1>

      <p>The year is 1963, the night: Halloween. Police are called to 43 Lampkin Ln. only to discover that 15 year old Judith Myers has been stabbed to death, by her 6 year-old brother, Michael. After being institutionalized for 15 years, Myers breaks out
        on the night before Halloween. No one knows, nor wants to find out, what will happen on October 31st 1978 besides Myers' psychiatrist, Dr. Loomis. He knows Michael is coming back to Haddonfield, but by the time the town realizes it, it'll be too
        late for many people.</p>

      <p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span>Donald Pleasence, Jamie Lee Curtis, Tony Moran</p>

      <p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>91 min</p>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="movie-showtimes">

    <ul class="movie-timing mon-listings">

      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>14:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>16:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>18:10</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>20:35</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>21:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>22:45</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>13:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>15:00</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>18:00</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>18:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>22:15</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>16:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>17:00</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>19:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>20:00</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>21:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>22:30</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>12:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>13:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>15:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>16:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>19:00</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>22:30</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>16:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>17:00</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>19:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>20:00</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>21:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>22:30</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>14:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>16:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>20:35</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>21:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>22:45</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>12:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>13:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>15:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>16:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>19:00</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>22:30</li>

    </ul>


  </div>

</div>

<div class="classic-movie">

  <div class="movie-summary">

    <div class="movie-image">

      <img src="images/movie-images/goodfellas.jpg" class="movie-thumbnail">

    </div>

    <div class="movie-name-plot">

      <h1>Goodfellas (1990)</h1>

      <p>Henry Hill might be a small time gangster, who may have taken part in a robbery with Jimmy Conway and Tommy De Vito, two other gangsters who might have set their sights a bit higher. His two partners could kill off everyone else involved in the
        robbery, and slowly start to think about climbing up through the hierarchy of the Mob. Henry, however, might be badly affected by his partners' success, but will he consider stooping low enough to bring about the downfall of Jimmy and Tommy?</p>

      <p><span class="white-mini-header">Starring:</span>Robert De Niro, Ray Liotta, Joe Pesci</p>

      <p><span class="white-mini-header">Runtime:</span>146 min</p>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="movie-showtimes">

    <ul class="movie-timing mon-listings show">

      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>12:25</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>13:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>14:50</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>17:35</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>20:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow mondaylisting">MONDAY<br>22:30</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>13:50</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>15:10</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>17:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>20:00</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>21:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement tuesdaylisting">TUESDAY<br>22:50</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>10:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>13:10</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>15:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>18:25</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>20:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement wednesdaylisting">WEDNESDAY<br>21:50</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>11:20</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>14:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>16:50</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>18:00</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>19:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement thursdaylisting">THURSDAY<br>22:15</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>10:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>13:10</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>15:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>18:25</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>20:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement fridaylisting">FRIDAY<br>21:50</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>13:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>14:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>18:10</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>19:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>20:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement saturdaylisting">SATURDAY<br>22:30</li>

      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>14:45</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>16:30</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>18:10</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>20:35</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>21:15</li>
      <li class="daytimeshow hideElement sundaylisting">SUNDAY<br>22:45</li>

    </ul>


  </div>

</div>

</div>
```